# Apache spark DataFrames join is failing using scala

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrames and a join operation between them, however the join is failing without citing any actual error.

```
//HospitalFacility class to fill in
case class HospitalFacility(Name: String, Rating: Int, Cost: Int);
//I pass the pid as an input parameter.
//hc : HiveConext successfully created
//Provider_Facility & Facility_Master are my two hive tables.
def fetchHospitalFacilityData(pid: String): String = {
   val filteredProviderSpecilaityDF = hc.sql("select FacilityId, Rating, Cost from Provider_Facility where ProviderId='" + pid + "'");
   println(filteredProviderSpecilaityDF);
   filteredProviderSpecilaityDF.foreach ( println ); //Prints perfectly

   val allFacilityDF = hc.sql("select id, Name from Facility_Master");
   println(allFacilityDF);
   allFacilityDF.foreach(println); //Prints perfectly

   //The below line throws error.
   val resultDF = filteredProviderSpecilaityDF.join(allFacilityDF,filteredProviderSpecilaityDF("FacilityId") === allFacilityDF("id") ,"right_outer"); 
   println(resultDF);

   val filteredFacilityList = resultDF.rdd.map { spec => HospitalFacility(spec.getString(0).toString(), spec.getInt(3), spec.getInt(4)) }.collect();
   filteredFacilityList.foreach(println); //does not reach this point
   return result;
  }
```

The error that is thrown is listed below :

```
Exception in thread "broadcast-hash-join-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Lscala/Function0;)V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.UnsafeHashedRelation.writeExternal(HashedRelation.scala:264)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeExternalData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1458)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1429)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:102)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.(TorrentBroadcast.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1326)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashOuterJoin$$anonfun$broadcastFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastHashOuterJoin.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashOuterJoin$$anonfun$broadcastFuture$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(BroadcastHashOuterJoin.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashOuterJoin$$anonfun$broadcastFuture$1.apply(BroadcastHashOuterJoin.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.joins.BroadcastHashOuterJoin$$anonfun$broadcastFuture$1.apply(BroadcastHashOuterJoin.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Check your scala/spark libraries and cluster versions ! You seem to have a mismatch of a kind

Comment: This is working from the Spark-shell but not from the Scala program

Comment: Can you create a minimum reproducible and verifiable example ? (Build file, code, spark version, how do you run it, etc) We won't be able to help you otherwise

Comment: Hi eliasah, I have provided the whole function. Can you please have a look now. Thanks.

Comment: Spark-hive :1.6.0, Spark-sql :1.6.0, Spark-core:1.6.3. I run them through Eclipse through a servlet.

Comment: This is still not reproducible with the given description and not likely to be solved. Many questions are solved by OPs in general just by creating the MVCE that I have mentioned. And as I said in the first comment, seems to me like versions mismatch between some libraries. So at least try to align your spark libraries. The spark-shell usually works because those libraries are aligned. I won't add anything further but thus the current state of the question. I'm voting to close it as missing the MVCE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `allFacilityDF("id")=== filteredProviderSpecilaityDF("FacilityId")`
return a boolean seq not a Seq[String]
The parm usingColumns is defined below:
Names of the columns to join on. This columns must exist on both sides.

Comment: I just ran it in my Spark-shell and its working fine. But when I run it through  the servlet its throwing the mentioned error. Anything that could go wrong if it is called from a scala program?